# Can anything bad happen to EDI as a squadmate?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So EDI is my latest squadmate. Something about taking my ship's AI out to get shot, bludgeoned or set on fire seems extremely ill-advised, but then this is a video game.

Can anything bad happen to the ship/it's AI if I take EDI out to play as a squad member or is she safe? If it's not, is there some specific mission I need to avoid taking her on?

Comment: Does getting caught up in a relationship with Joker count as 'anything bad?'

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz that's...well, yes. But not quite for the purposes of this question.

Comment: Once his bones finish breaking, they should be good, right?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Joker's line about "over the clothes" fun is probably my favorite quote from this series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak to the possibility of a specific mission that will result in a negative effects., but dying in mission has no negative effects any more than it does on any other character.

Comment: But EDI states that she is present in both the body and the ship, from that I can assume that the body is only effected

Answer (score -4):

On Rannoch to deliver the civilian fleet admiral from danger, there's a slight line where she references there being an increased transmission breakup and not just lag due tot the jamming towers, and it did seem she failed to follow my orders on occasion but thats probably just the game more than an effect of that line.

As far as I can tell, thats the only bit where it seemed like anything came of it.